# How can I set my first row vertical align to center

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I use `align-items-center` class in row section but it doesn't work:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-12 bg-warning">
            hello
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want that line be vertical centered on page as I show in the picture:

[image]

Comment: How about `text-align: center` ?

Comment: @Mr. x i want  vertical align column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working fine but you have to set a `height`. At the moment the `.container` and `.row` took the height of the content. So you have to set a `height` to the `.row` and your `.col` should be vertical centered:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-center" style="height:500px;">
        <div class="col-12 bg-warning">
            hello
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To set vertical center on the visible area of your site, you can use `height:100vh;` instead of the fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the page occupy 100% high.

```
html, body, .container, .row {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/q1ypnzg8/2/

```html
<div class="container divouter">
    <div class="row align-items-center divmiddle">
        <div class="col-12 bg-warning divinner">
            hello
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.divouter {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.divmiddle {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.divinner {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS has limitations when it comes to putting a text there at the center. For browser compatibility, I'd advice you to use inline alignment property.

```
<div align="center">Content goes here.</div>
```

Other properties you can use in case of CSS include:

`#divID{ margin:auto`
`text-align: center;`

```
}
```

Though, I'd prefer the margin auto property since the text align may fail in certain browsers for certain tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this css for .row.align-items-center

```css
.row.align-items-center {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Hope this will help.